# Should we choose a meaningful domain name or a easy to type domain name?

Tags: mobile, accessibility, mobile-web, urls, seo

So as we expected, most users are visiting website on their phone, for some big phones there might be this issue, but if you're an iPhone 5 user or other 4 inch phone user you might found out that you will frequently type the wrong letter on the keyboard, although the system will fix it, it won't be fixed in the browsers' URL bar.

When you're building your personal site (blog, portfolio, project site), should you choose a meaningful domain e.g. `christmascard(.)com` or something that is easy to type e.g. `qwerty(.)com`?

So here is what I consider, `christmascard` has a higher possibility to be typed wrong, while `qwerty` has a lesser chance since the alphabet is next to the previous letter.

So should we choose a meaningful domain but have a higher chance to get typed wrong or an easy to type domain but not meaningful? Or it doesn't matter at all since SEO is more important?

Comment: It would be okay to buy something available, like ux-designers.com, which is still available as I can see and also catchy plus potential SEO gold domain name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Memory is the limiting factor for type-in traffic

A domain name is *a little* like a password. When you are typing it, you have to remember it exactly right, or you fail. If users forget one detail of your domain name, they cannot type it.

(Consider how much less stressful it is when you think you mistyped a password, than when you think you forgot it.)

Since [meaningful things are much easier to remember than meaningless ones](https://xkcd.com/936/), this leans us pretty strongly towards "meaningful."

It's easy to re-type a mispelled word. It's hard to "re-remember" a forgotten letter.

Comment: But for example qwerty you are not remembering the letters at all you will just know "oh! 6 letter strength from first row", or for asdcxz you'll think "a circle at the left bottom of the keyboard, with this kind of condition will it be preferred or still prefer a meaningful one?

Comment: @Munucial, have a peak at that XKCD link I put in there - things like which way the circle turns won't be super-easy to remember. *Muscle memory* might play some part in passwords that are shapes, but switch devices and you've lost that.

Answer (score 0):

Go with an easy to type domain. It means more people will find your website.

A co-worker of mine has his own business on the side. He went with a meaningful domain where he changed the way you write an ordinary word. Now he has to explain to everybody he talks to; 'No, not with a C but with a Q'. That doesn't look good for your image and how you come across.

Comment: The problem with your co-worker's domain appears to be not that he chose a meaningful domain over an easy-to-type domain, but that he chose a domain that has an in-built typing trap.